# How to disable UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UICollectionViewCell after there is a long press?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uigesturerecognizer

Currently, I have a collection view with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on the cell in `cellForItemAt`:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPressOnCell))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

When the user holds down on a cell, it triggers a function to show a menu called `cellDeleteAppear()`. However, after the menu is on the screen, the user can then hold down on another cell which will cause the menu to pop up again.

```
@objc func handleLongPressOnCell(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began {

            cellDeleteAppear()

            let gestureLocation = sender.location(in: self.trayCollectionView)

            if let indexPath = self.trayCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gestureLocation) {

            indexPathForDeletion = indexPath

            trayCollectionView.allowsSelection = false

            } else {
                print("long press error at index path")
            }
        }
    }
```

My goal is: while the menu is active, the user should not be able to hold down on another cell to trigger the menu to pop up. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then do

```
var menuShown = false
@objc func handleLongPressOnCell(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
   if sender.state == .began {
      guard !menuShown else { return }
      menuShown = true
```

And when you hide it do

```
menuShown = false
```